# Why postgres database server slows down after dump/restore with --no-owner option?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-dump

When I do dump/restore everything works fine. But when I add option `--no-owner` and dump/restore database the queries slows down.
For example one complex query run about **3 minues instead of 1sec** before dump/restore

**The only thing that is changed is `--no-owner` for `pg_dump` utility**

I suppose when dump with `--no-owner` option and restore such database then user, which restore database, has no access to index info. But this is just assumption

**DETAILS**
`make docker-dbdump && make docker-dbrestore` slows down query execution:

```sh
.ONESHELL:
docker-dbdump:
    file=${APP_ROOT}/db/${DB_NAME}-$$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").sql.gz
    docker exec ${DOCKER_CONTAINER} pg_dump --no-owner -U postgres ${DB_NAME} \
      | gzip -f > $${file}
    cp $${file} ${APP_ROOT}/db/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz

docker-dbrestore: dbclear
    zcat ${APP_ROOT}/db/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz | \
        docker exec -i ${DOCKER_CONTAINER} psql -U ${DB_USER} -d ${DB_NAME}
```

When I remove `--no-owner` options then everything is fine.

**UPD**

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "btree_gist"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
ERROR:  extension "btree_gist" does not exist
...
ERROR:  data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

I want to compare how database is dumped with and w/o `--no-owner` option and show later today

Comment: That seems unlikely. Check for error messages during restore. Add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for a fast and a slow execution of the same query to the question.

Comment: If you cannot install `btree_gist`, a later index creation fails. That is probably the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: you are right. `btree_gist` could not be created database owner. Only superuser. I also have couple: `ERROR:  must be member of role "postgres"`. How to find out which functions was not created?

Comment: Read all error messages.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: There are about hundred `ALTER FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION` messages. I do not know to which one belongs `ERROR` message: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/592585. Currently I just count all of them. Then count messages in dumped `sql.gz` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slows down because of error:

```
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
ERROR:  extension "btree_gist" does not exist
```

Extension is not created, so related indexes also are not created.

Without indexes database slows-down =(

When I fixed error with rights all also starts to work super fast!